# How to fire deviceBackButton on `v-ons-alert-dialog`

Tags: vue.js, onsen-ui

In documentation, `deviceBackButton` is fired on device back button. It isn't fired on device back button in my application.
Device back button terminates my application without showing alert dialog. I don't want to terminate app.

```
<template>
  <v-ons-alert-dialog
    @deviceBackButton="backButtonEvent"
  >
    ...
  </v-ons-alert-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    backButtonEvent(event) {
      alert('hello, world');
      return event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Onsen UI.

The bug has now been fixed but not released yet:
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/commit/f55de7910

It will be included in the next patch release of Onsen UI.

So to answer your question, you can make sure the `deviceBackButton` handler is called by building Onsen UI from master and using that in your project, or you can use the next version when it is released.